# Magento goes first the HTTP then redirects to HTTPS

Tags: ce-1.9.0.1, optimization

How can I make magento store go directly to HTTPS to save me 0.3-0.5 second of initial page load time going to HTTP then going back to HTTPS?

I am completely lost here.

Comment: What url do you have as your Base_url in admin https or http?

Comment: I have https:// in both unsecure and secure options under:system / config / general / web.

Comment: Where are users getting the non https version from?

Answer (score 3):

The 0.3-0.5 seconds delay seem to be coming from magento internal redirect, so I would recommend using your server .htaccess to do your redirecting

See  [htaccess redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13977851/htaccess-redirect-to-https-www)

Add the top of your .htaccess file add

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
# First rewrite to HTTPS:
# Don't put www. here. If it is already there it will be included, if not
# the subsequent rule will catch it.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
# Now, rewrite any request to the wrong domain to use www.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks for the responses I am reading through this now.  Unfortunately I am a slow learner.

Comment: THanks! And now how would this statement look if the original domain is *without* www - say: the other way around?

Comment: Try removing the last 3 lines

Answer (score 1):

this works in Magento 1.9.1
use your app/etc/config.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <frontend>
    <secure_url>
      <all>/</all>
    </secure_url>
  </frontend>
</config>
```

If user is using https, this should force all urls to rewrite (created as) to https.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to install https://github.com/ikonoshirt/StrictTransportSecurity

this is a plugin which install HSTS - HTTP Strict Transport Security in your shop.

The consequence is, that a HTTP header is sent, which disallows the browser to connect unencrypted to the website. So every request is made via HTTPS.

To do this, you have to configure both base urls to be https.

Comment: No need for a module, just set the header in the .htaccess

Comment: The module makes a few more things, but you are right. Just writing it in htaccess (better in vhost config) solves the problem too.